# moving average of all data to current value

Tags: r

I'd like to calculate the moving average of a vector using all the values till the current value. So that:

```
c(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 10)
```

would return

```
 1.00 1.50 1.33 2.00 2.60 3.83
```

I used a loop like this:

```
out = c()
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  m = mean(x[1:i])
  out = c(out, m)
}
```

Are there any packages with a built in function for this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)`. This is called a *cumulative mean*.

Comment: `dplyr::cummean(c(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 10))`

Comment: thanks! didn't know the name of the operation. duplicate covers it well

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
v <- c(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 10)
cumsum(v)/(1:length(v))
```